# How to configure the niceness or priority of service started on boot

Tags: centos6, service, limits, nice, process-priority

I want to increase the **niceness of an service** (decrease the CPU priority) started as an dedicated user or group during the boot process. I'm not able to define the niceness or priority in the `/etc/security/limits.conf` or `./limits.d/` directory for the desired user because the entry will not be observed for services. (?)

#### Example

In particular I've a few small vServers with CentOS 6.6 and want to run a tor relay ([The Onion Router](https://www.torproject.org/)) on each.
The tor daemon starts on boot as a service, configured via `sudo /sbin/chkconfig` (run level: 2,3,4,5). The user and group for the tor process is `_tor`.

Where do I have to change the nice or priority level for every process the user _tor is the owner?
The nice value should be applied on every boot and on manual service start (`service tor start`).

Comment: Using nice/ionice is a bit of a dated approach. Are you currently experiencing performance problems?

Answer (score 0):

The classical approach is to use `nice` and/or `ionice` within the service start-up script. You probably have something like:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
    echo "Starting tor daemon"
    /path/to/tor-daemon
```

and change that to

```
    echo "Starting tor daemon"
    nice /path/to/tor-daemon
```

Alternatively the start-up script often logs the PID of a daemon in `/var/run/pid-of-tor-daemon` or similar and you could use `renice` on that PID after the daemon has started.

---

A better approach is with cgroups. That is slightly too long for an answer here, but the [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html) might be a useful start.